# Can't get values for multiple checkbox in Codeigniter (part2)

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, checkbox

I did ask the same questions before but I dont understand why it doesn't work now. When I click to open the modal (for edit function), the data is not populate, only role_id is populated in the modal. Is it something to do with jquery version or Codeigniter new update or something else ? The following are my codes. appreciate your kind advice.

**view/rolelist.php**

The javascript goes here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                $('.edit-row').on('click',function(){
                                    var me = $(this);
                                    var editModal = $('#myModalEdit');
                                    editModal.find('#role_id').val(me.attr('data-roleID'));
                                    editModal.find('#role_name').val(me.attr('data-roleName'));
                                    editModal.find('#manage_user').val(me.attr('data-manageUser'));
                                    editModal.find('#manage_product').val(me.attr('data-manageProduct'));
                                    editModal.find('#manage_project').val(me.attr('data-manageProject'));
                                    editModal.find('#manage_timeline').val(me.attr('data-manageTimeline'));
                                    editModal.find('#fn_trace').val(me.attr('data-fnTrace'));
                                    editModal.find('#fn_mapper').val(me.attr('data-fnMapper'));
                                    editModal.find('#fn_testscript').val(me.attr('data-fnTestScript'));
                                    editModal.find('#fn_project').val(me.attr('data-fnProject'));
                                    $('#myModalEdit').modal('show');
                                });
                            });
</script>
```

HTML Code

```
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit System Role <label id="role_name"></label></h4>
            </div>

        <form role="form" id="roleForm" action="<?php echo base_url().'admin/updateRole'; ?>" method= "POST">
            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Role ID [Auto-generate by system]</label>                                    
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="role_id" id="role_id" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Role Name *</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="role_name" id="role_name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                    <thead style="background-color:#33658A; color:#FFF;">
                      <tr>
                                <th colspan="4"><strong><center>ADMIN FUNCTIONS</center></strong></th>
                                <th colspan="4"><strong><center>QA FUNCTIONS</center></strong></th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                                <th><strong><center>MANAGE USER</center></strong></th>
                                <th><strong><center>MANAGE PRODUCT</center></strong></th>
                                <th><strong><center>MANAGE PROJECT</center></strong></th>
                                <th><strong><center>MANAGE TIMELINE</center></strong></th>
                                <th><strong><center>TRACE</center></strong></th>
                                <th><strong><center>MAPPER</center></strong></th>
                                <th><strong><center>TEST SCRIPT</center></strong></th>
                                <th><strong><center>PROJECT</center></strong></th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <div class="checkbox">
                      <tr>
                          <td><input type="checkbox" name="manage_user" id="manage_user" value="manage_user" style="margin-left:20px"></td>                           
                          <td><input type="checkbox" name="manage_product" id="manage_product" value="manage_product" style="margin-left:20px"></td>                              
                          <td><input type="checkbox" name="manage_project" id="manage_project" value="manage_project" style="margin-left:20px"></td>                              
                          <td><input type="checkbox" name="manage_timeline" id="manage_timeline" value="manage_timeline" style="margin-left:20px"></td>                           
                          <td><input type="checkbox" name="fn_trace" id="fn_trace" value="fn_trace" style="margin-left:20px"></td>                            
                          <td><input type="checkbox" name="fn_mapper" id="fn_mapper" value="fn_mapper" style="margin-left:20px"></td>                             
                          <td><input type="checkbox" name="fn_testscript" id="fn_testscript" value="fn_testscript" style="margin-left:20px"></td>                             
                          <td><input type="checkbox" name="fn_project" id="fn_project" value="fn_project" style="margin-left:20px"></td>                              
                      </tr>
                      </div> <!-- end checkbox -->
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            </div> <!-- end modal-body -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Update Info</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div> <!-- /.modalEdit -->

    <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <div class="content-panel">
                      <section id="unseen">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
                          <thead style="background-color:#33658A; color:#FFF;">
                          <tr>
                                <th rowspan="2"><h4><strong>ROLE ID</strong></h4></th>
                                <th rowspan="2"><h4><strong>ROLE NAME</strong></h4></th>
                                <th colspan="4"><h4><strong><center>ADMIN FUNCTIONS</center></strong></h4></th>
                                <th colspan="4"><h4><strong><center>QA FUNCTIONS</center></strong></h4></th>
                                <th rowspan="2"><h4><center><strong>ACTION</strong></center></h4></th>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                                <th><h4><strong>MANAGE USER</strong></h4></th>
                                <th><h4><strong>MANAGE PRODUCT</strong></h4></th>
                                <th><h4><strong>MANAGE PROJECT</strong></h4></th>
                                <th><h4><strong>MANAGE TIMELINE</strong></h4></th>
                                <th><h4><strong>TRACE</strong></h4></th>
                                <th><h4><strong>MAPPER</strong></h4></th>
                                <th><h4><strong>TEST SCRIPT</strong></h4></th>
                                <th><h4><strong>PROJECT</strong></h4></th>
                          </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                          <?php
                if(!empty($data_role)):
                foreach($data_role as $row)
                {
              ?>
              <tr>                  
                <td align="center"><?php echo $row->role_id; ?></td>                            
                <td><?php echo $row->role_name; ?></td>

              <?php
                echo '<td>'.$row->adm_manage_user.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row->adm_manage_product.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row->adm_manage_project.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row->adm_manage_timeline.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row->fn_trace.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row->fn_mapper.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row->fn_test_script.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row->fn_project.'</td>';
                echo '<td class="text-center">';
              ?>
              <a href="<?php echo base_url().'admin/roleRemove/'.$row->role_id; ?>">
                <button type="button" data-hover="tooltip" title="Delete Role <?php echo $row->role_name; ?>" class="btn btn-default">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </button>
              </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

              <a class="edit-row" href="javascript:" 
                data-roleID="<?php echo $row->role_id; ?>"
                data-roleName="<?php echo $row->role_name; ?>"
                data-manageUser="<?php echo $row->adm_manage_user; ?>"
                data-manageProduct="<?php echo $row->adm_manage_product; ?>"
                data-manageProject="<?php echo $row->adm_manage_project; ?>"
                data-manageTimeline="<?php echo $row->adm_manage_timeline; ?>"
                data-fnTrace="<?php echo $row->fn_trace; ?>"
                data-fnMapper="<?php echo $row->fn_mapper; ?>"
                data-fnTestScript="<?php echo $row->fn_test_script; ?>"
                data-fnProject="<?php echo $row->fn_project; ?>"
              > 
              <button type="button" data-hover="tooltip" title="Edit Role <?php echo $row->role_name; ?>" class="btn btn-default">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
              </button>
              </a>

              <?php
                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
                }
                endif;
              ?>
                          </tbody>
                      </table>
                      </section>
              </div><!-- /content-panel -->
            </div><!-- /col-lg-12 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

use same `name` for all checkboxes if its related to each other.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="manage[]" id="manage_user" value="manage_user" style="margin-left:20px"></td> 
<td><input type="checkbox" name="manage[]" id="manage_product" value="manage_product" style="margin-left:20px"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="manage[]" id="manage_project" value="manage_project" style="margin-left:20px"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="manage[]" id="manage_timeline" value="manage_timeline" style="margin-left:20px"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="manage[]" id="fn_trace" value="fn_trace" style="margin-left:20px"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="manage[]" id="fn_mapper" value="fn_mapper" style="margin-left:20px"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="manage[]" id="fn_testscript" value="fn_testscript" style="margin-left:20px"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="manage[]" id="fn_project" value="fn_project" style="margin-left:20px"></td>
```

And access the checkbox values with the name `$this->input->post('manage');` .

Comment: Thanks.. but still not solve my problem.. i still unable to get checked for the checkbox

Comment: You dont have form tag in popup. on form submit values will go to php controller.

Comment: I dont understand.. which form tag you are referring to?

Comment: you edited the code, when i commented there was no form tag.

Comment: i didnt edit the code @mayoori .. but thanks.. I think i got the problem.. i'll try fix it.. thanks again